# MySQL- How can I extract the monday given a number of week?

Tags: mysql, date, timestamp

Essentially what I want to obtain is the monday given the number of the week::

I have week: 9, 7,5

This number of week corresponds to a timestamp:

```
2019-03-02 02:48:00, 
2019-02-15 02:58:00, 
2019-01-31 00:25:00
```

I want to obtain the date of the monday of this week(first day of week):

```
2/25,
2/11, 
1/28
```

How can extract this outout? it can be extracted from timestamp if it is easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get Monday of the week.

You can try to use `DATE_ADD` and `WEEKDAY` function.

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(dt, INTERVAL - WEEKDAY(dt) DAY)
FROM T
```

[sqlfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cBh4kZYoMJ3nb914aVizeY/0)

**EDIT**

There is another function `DATE_FORMAT` represent to the date format string.

> using `"%m/%d"`

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(
  DATE_ADD(dt, INTERVAL - WEEKDAY(dt) DAY), "%m/%d")
FROM T
```

[sqlfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cBh4kZYoMJ3nb914aVizeY/1)

Comment: Hello, this query is returning the same timestamp as before: 2019-01-21 23:48:00

Comment: Nice one, you can do this too `dt + INTERVAL - WEEKDAY(dt) DAY`

Comment: @J.CGuzman, it should return the expected output. can you show us what are you trying here.

Comment: Well I have the correct date, but not the desired output, how can I convert this timestamp in this format: 2/25, I am getting an error and I don't know how to solve it